# Passing a Variable as Parameter to PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

i'm trying to pass a variable as a parameter from one to another powershell skript.

The following code is working fine:
`start powershell {./Test2.ps1 "Hello world."}`

```
param ($param1)
write-host $param1
PowerShell -NoExit
```

Now I want to pass a variable from the first powershell skript to the second script like this:

```
$test = Read-Host "Please input a text:"
start powershell {./Test2.ps1 $test}
```

```
param ($param1)
write-host $param1
PowerShell -NoExit
```

Does someone know why this code doesn't work?

Comment: whats the error/output you are getting?

Comment: `$test` is not available because you're launching a separate process. Do `./Test2.ps1 $test` without the `start powershell {...}` part and it'll work :)

Comment: As  commented by @Mathias, you probably making it more difficult than is supposed to be: Why launching a new process (`Start(-process)`), why launching a new PowerShell session? Why creating an expression `{...}`? You probably just want to do just: `./Test2.ps1 $test`